# array_push for multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as follows:

```
$sql_commands_to_run=    Array
    (
        [0] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table3`]} {[ADD COLUMN `con` varchar(25) NULL;
        [1] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2`]} {[MODIFY COLUMN `mobile2` varchar(15), ADD UNIQUE(`mobile2`);
        [2] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2`]} {[MODIFY `type2` varchar(10)  NOT NULL;
        [3] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2`]} {[MODIFY COLUMN `type2` varchar(10);
        [4] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2`]} {[ADD COLUMN `email2` varchar(255);
    )
```

I want to merge the multiple alter queries into one query per table

```
Array
(
    [0] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table3` ADD COLUMN `con` varchar(25) NULL;
    [1] => ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2` MODIFY COLUMN `mobile2` varchar(15), ADD UNIQUE(`mobile2`),MODIFY `type2` varchar(10)  NOT NULL,MODIFY COLUMN `type2` varchar(10),ADD COLUMN `email2` varchar(255);
)
```

for that to happen I am trying to separate the table names with the modifications

```
Array(
['ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table3`'] => Array(
                                            [0] => 'ADD COLUMN `con` varchar(25) NULL'
                                            ),
['ALTER TABLE `live`.`master_table_2`'] => Array(
                                                [0] => 'MODIFY COLUMN `mobile2` varchar(15)',
                                                [1] => 'ADD UNIQUE(`mobile2`)',
                                                [2] => 'MODIFY `type2` varchar(10)  NOT NULL',
                                                [3] => 'MODIFY COLUMN `type2` varchar(10)',
                                                [4] => 'ADD COLUMN `email2` varchar(255)'
                                                )                                       
)
```

here is what I am trying :

```
$merger = array();
foreach($sql_commands_to_run as $sql_command){            
            $temp_arr = explode("]} {[",$sql_command);            
            array_push($merger["'".$temp_arr[0]."'"],$temp_arr[1]);
        }
```

but I'm not good at arrays. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$merger[$temp_arr[0]][] =  $temp_arr[1];` instead array_push

Comment: The source array that you have is a real mess, I can see roughly what you are trying to do but the data held in `$sql_commands_to_run` is far from ideal. Where does `$sql_commands_to_run` come from? Show us the code please

Comment: Maybe you should write that as an answer @splash58

Comment: Why not just `str_replace(']} {[', ' ', $sql_commands_to_run)`? Oh I see, you want 1 query per table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change line with array_push with

```
$merger[$temp_arr[0]][] = $temp_arr[1];
```

[demo](https://eval.in/892197)

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use array_push() just set the value....

```
$merger = array();
foreach($sql_commands_to_run as $sql_command){            
        $temp_arr = explode("]} {[",$sql_command);            
        $merger[$temp_arr[0]][]=$temp_arr[1];
}
```